# Prolog print numbers from 1 to N?

Tags: prolog

Assume the user gives an input N to the function, how would I print these numbers from 1 to N (recursively or other wise).

example

print_numbers(40).

->1 
->2 
->… 
->40

Comment: Please show what you've tried and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to print numbers from 1 to N so print_numbers(N) can be translated in print_numbers(1, N).

Now what is print_numbers from X to Y ?

print_numbers from X to Y is print(X) and print_numbers from X+1 to N!

In Prolog, you will get :

```
print_numbers(N) :-
    print_numbers(1, N).

% general case X must be lower than Y
print_numbers(X, Y) :-
    X =< Y,
    writeln(X),
    X1 is X + 1,
    print_numbers(X1, Y).
```

Comment: Nice answer, although this fails after printing the numbers, which makes it difficult to use.

Comment: change `print_numbers(X1, Y)` to `ignore(print_numbers(X1, Y))` to make it succeed.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`between/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=between/3) and [`forall/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2):

```
?- forall(between(1, 40, X), writeln(X))
1
2
3
...
39
40
true.
```